# JavaScript not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, infopath

I have put a snippet of JavaScript into a Script Editor Web Part. It's function is to display an alert box and redirect the page after an Infopath form submission. I got it from this website and modified it.

https://askmanisha.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/redirection-to-a-page-on-infopath-form-closure-inside-an-infopath-form-web-part/

```
    <script>
 function pagecontainerload()
 {
  setTimeout(setEventHandler,5000);
 }

 function setEventHandler()
 {
  var btnSend = document.getElementById("ButtonID");

  btnSend.onmouseup = function(){Button.OnClick(this, event); alert("Your request has been successfuly submitted.");      window.location='website.com';};
 }
 </script>
```

The script works fine in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the web console for errors. Better yet install firebug and check the console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the `event` being undefined.  IE and Chrome are okay with it, but FF doesn't like it.  In the last line, the code should be `function(event){Button.OnClick(this, event)`

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. I see the same issue in my browser

Answer (score 0):

May be something: under IE, `getElementById` looks for elements by `ID` and by `name`, while under FF, it's only by `ID`. Are you sure your `ButtonID` element has its `ID` set to `ButtonID` and not only its name?

If the `name` attribute has to be used, you may call `getElementsByName` instead (mind it may return more than one element).

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote "Button ID" in instead of the actual ID since it was so long and I didn't think it was that important.  So it is not looking for the name, but the ID.